Prove that 2 points on the curve and it's slope field are enough to find the curve.
I was trying to understand the geometrical interpretation of the differential equations beacause a lot of times while solving problems in physics,I get DE's and then we put the limits and get it solved. I am always able to get to the correct answer but i didn't understood how it happens.So today i watched a video to understand it on youtube: https://youtu.be/ccDMpj2UK_M?si=dA168HLT-ArcMxbf
But i couldn't understand why 2 points which we put as limits while soving DE and slope field are enough to give us the exact curve. Thus i am looking for a mathematically rigrous proof of this.If anybody could help i would be really be greatful.

Cauchy Lipschitz theorem.

What type of differential equation are you solving? If you have a first order differential equation, you can just use 1 point, but you mention 2 points

@student91 let's say i am working working first order differential equation. Can you please help me with the proof? So that i can try to generalise it for nth order.

You need a second order ode if two points are considered ... an initial point and initial slope. OR, initial and final points.

@Narasimham Bro can you please help me with the proof

In some examples consider how many arbitrary constants arise when integrating an ODE, and, its order.

The full result you are asking for is the Picard–Lindelöf theorem, aka Cauchy-Lipschitz. But it isn't an easy proof, and it only proves local uniqueness (see "Example of non-uniqueness" on the wikipedia page). For linear differential equations, a simpler proof starts with $y' = 0$ has only constant solutions, proved using the mean-value theorem. Then it moves to higher derivatives using induction. You should be able to find it in your textbook.
